# Can I list privileges that were granted DIRECTLY to a user in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Seems like simple selects from **session_privs** and **user_sys_privs** give all current privileges, but I cannot differentiate which of them are inherited from a role and which were granted directly.

Is there a way of listing ONLY directly granted privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you query `dictionary`, here's some interesting result:

```
SQL> select * from dictionary where lower(table_name) like '%user%privs%' order by table_name;

TABLE_NAME                     COMMENTS
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------
USER_AQ_AGENT_PRIVS
USER_COL_PRIVS                 Grants on columns for which the user is the owner, grantor or grantee
USER_COL_PRIVS_MADE            All grants on columns of objects owned by the user
USER_COL_PRIVS_RECD            Grants on columns for which the user is the grantee
USER_ROLE_PRIVS                Roles granted to current user
USER_RSRC_CONSUMER_GROUP_PRIVS Switch privileges for consumer groups for the user
USER_RSRC_MANAGER_SYSTEM_PRIVS system privileges for the resource manager for the user
USER_SYS_PRIVS                 System privileges granted to current user
USER_TAB_PRIVS                 Grants on objects for which the user is the owner, grantor or grantee
USER_TAB_PRIVS_MADE            All grants on objects owned by the user
USER_TAB_PRIVS_RECD            Grants on objects for which the user is the grantee

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Views you might be interested in - as they show privileges granted directly to you - are

- user_sys_privs
- user_tab_privs
- user_role_privs